# Adding sound to game. Help needed

Tags: java, audio

So I have this code, and I would like to know how could I join it with the rest of my game, 'cause the only way it plays sound now is by selecting this class as a launcher. Also, could I get some info, what exactly is changed and why. I feel like I should get a better understanding of this code, since I just found the code, and pasted it :D
Code:

```
package main;

import main.Handler;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;


public class AudioPlayer implements LineListener {

    boolean playCompleted;

    void play(String audioFilePath) {
        File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);

        try {
            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

            AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

            Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            audioClip.addLineListener(this);

            audioClip.open(audioStream);

            audioClip.start();

            while (!playCompleted) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            audioClip.close();

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            System.out.println("The specified audio file is not supported.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            System.out.println("Audio line for playing back is unavailable.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error playing the audio file.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        LineEvent.Type type = event.getType();

        if (type == LineEvent.Type.START) {
            System.out.println("Playback started.");

        } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            playCompleted = true;
            System.out.println("Playback completed.");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String audioFilePath = "res/music/dark_theme.wav";
        AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();
        player.play(audioFilePath);
    }


    }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class is a fairly normal class to use: Construct an instance, call some methods, and it does what it is expected to do. When you are using it as a launcher, all you're doing is calling the main method, which serves as an example of how to use this class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String audioFilePath = "res/music/dark_theme.wav";
    AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();
    player.play(audioFilePath);
}
```

Just construct an instance, and call `play()` on it with the name of the audio file intended.

However, be warned that this class isn't really a good example of how to go about doing this, for a few reasons:

- It blocks while playing, meaning that you can't start playing sound and go about doing something different at the same time.
- It can't play a sound more than once without incurring issues.

So, let's modify this class to not have these issues. This class will let you load a clip into memory, and start it asynchronously (meaning that you start it and then your program keeps running). The start() method starts it to play once, and the loop() method loops it forever. stop() is self-explanatory, and cleanup() should be called to release resources once you no longer need this audio clip. (Of course, if you intend to start playing the clip again soon, you should not cleanup() at that point).

```
import main.Handler;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class AudioPlayer{
    Clip audioClip;
    boolean playCompleted;
    String path;
    public AudioPlayer(String path){
        this.path = path;
        File audioFile = new File(path);

        try {
            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

            AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

            audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            audioClip.open(audioStream);

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            System.out.println("The specified audio file is not supported.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            System.out.println("Audio line for playing back is unavailable.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error playing the audio file.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    void play() {
        audioClip.start();

    }
    void loop(){
        audioClip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
    void stop(){
        audioClip.stop();
    }
    void cleanup(){
        audioClip.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String audioFilePath = "res/music/dark_theme.wav";
        AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer(audioFilePath);
        player.play();
        // give the sound time to play
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank You, It makes more sense now :D Also, could You explain, how do I make it loop?

Comment: @Krycer Just a moment, I'm restructuring this post completely and re-writing this class to have more features and not encounter some of the issues I spoke about.

Comment: Also, by blocking, do You mean, that It cannot for example move my player, while I'm playing it?

Comment: @Krycer Correct, you can't do anything until it finishes, unless you use a specialized feature called multithreading.

Comment: @Krycer You still need the same imports.

Comment: @Krycer What line is stating that Clip can't be resolved? Edit: Fixed. What threw me off was that your comment had `Clip` in uppercase letters, not lowercase, so I was looking at the imports.

Comment: XD Don't worry.. I know the feels.. Even when not in Java

Comment: For some reason I hear nothing... That I weird... Is there anything that I need to do with other classes? Also, I'd probably need to up my reputation so, y'know

Comment: @Krycer If you're calling the main method, then the program will exit before the sound has a chance to play. Try calling it from your game, where you won't exit the application for a few seconds after calling `play()`. Remember that we modified it so it's no longer blocking.

Comment: How do I know that? I can drop my eclipse workspace folder, so You can check freely.

Comment: @Krycer Let me try it on my end, and see what's up.

Comment: @Krycer The latest version of the code (direct copy-paste from what I wrote here) works on my computer. Again, the `main` method is only an example. I'm not sure of the organization of your game, so I've made the class as flexible as possible: You can construct an audioplayer at any time, then start/stop/loop it later, then clean up in the very end.

Comment: Ok. But If You can please try to fix it. It's not like I'm lazy, but I hardly get what You're saying :D Here's link to my project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Frru2_b0iScnVEYmdLb2F3Wnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Krycer I updated the code in my answer. Please make sure you're using the most up-to-date one (since your ZIP had an older version of my answer with an error in it).

Comment: Okey dokey amigo! (Had to write something for the character limit :D)

Comment: Uhm.. Still problems. And that wasn't up to date, 'cause I didn't exit eclipse, so it would save my workspace

Comment: @Krycer To clarify, the `AudioPlayer.java` with [this specific contents (link)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14796016/) works with my system. I'd need to see an error message to debug further, since it's otherwise just guesswork.

Comment: Here's the new ZIP: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Frru2_b0iSS0Zrb2V4MjhWUlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Krycer When I run the `AudioPlayer` class in that zip (on a Windows machine), it works for me. Sorry I'm not able to figure out what's going on exactly.

Comment: Mmm.. Does it play the game? Do You run it from Launcher(1)?

Comment: @Krycer It won't play music if I call it from Launcher, since you never added code to your game that uses my audio player class. The AudioPlayer class needs to be actively used, not just simply "be there". At the start of your game, do `AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer(audioFilePath);
        player.play();` where `audioFilePath` is the path to the background music you want to play.

Comment: @Krycer Here's an updated `Game` class that works: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14797178/ Anyway I have to go; it's quite late in my timezone.

Comment: Syntax error on token "play", Identifier expected after this token. -_-

Comment: Oh ok. Thank You very very much. Was stuck on this problem for quite a while now... Also, don't think it's like 3pm here. It's 5am. I don't feel like sleeping :D